# A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required

Tags: docker, .net-core

I am running dotnet core 2.0 console project. 
Ran into the following error when trying to run it from Docker.

> A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required
>   to execute the application was not found in '/app'.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For me it was the following line that I had to add to the project file's **PropertyGroup** section that did the trick:

```xml
<GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
```

[image: Project file excerpt]

Comment: I was experiencing same error but with a Xunit Test project after upgrading to netcore 3.1. Adding this attribute resolved the issue. Thanks Rodion!

Comment: My mistake was I have changed `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`

Answer (score 8):

After some googleing I found this:
https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/issues/301

> I'm not certain what caused it but it seems to have gone away. It's
>   probably because I had a case mismatch of appSettings.json instead of
>   appsettings.json which meant that the file was not being loaded.
>   Terrible error though.

In my case it was that I had forgot to put appsettings.json to copy on builds.

[image]

Hope this helps someone else and get's higher on google searches.

Comment: Just sharing: doesn't seem to exist for .Net 6.0 console

Answer (score 8):

So none of the above answers worked for me, but I finally found the problem, it was something in the .csproj file of the API, and it was causing the docker container hosting the API not to start with the message in the thread title.

This was the line that had been added in `PropertyGroup` node, presumably when someone had published the file for windows, and then checked in the updated .csproj

`<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>`

As it turns out this is a publish option. Removing this sets the project to a default value of portable (in the UI) which is "any" in the file if it were explicitly specified. Removing the line above fixed the problem for me.

**Edit**

As a side note, I was able to leave the `RuntimeIdentifier` in the API .csproj file alone (kept `win-x64` value) by changing my Dockerfile dotnet publish args to:

```
RUN dotnet publish ./src/API.csproj --self-contained --runtime linux-musl-x64 --configuration Release --output /app/publish
```

The important parts being the addition of `--self-contained` and `--runtime linux-musl-x64` for alpine-linux ... this image: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-alpine`

The build image for this is `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1`

Comment: As I'm running an app on docker in a machine with ARM64 chips (M1 and M2), it was required to update the runtime to `linux-arm64`.

Answer (score 6):

After even more googling, we found this link:

http://szahariev.blogspot.co.nz/2016/10/libhostpolicyso-was-not-found-error.html

which lead us to discover that we'd somehow managed to manually remove the (in our case) `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` line from our .csproj file. So no *runtimeconfig.json* was created at all.

Comment: just had the same error. I had copied some files into a new project, but forgot that the new project was set to a Class Library output when it needed to be of a Console Application type

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was specified .dll to run was incorrect (library instead of web application).

First I acvieve successfull service start with

```
dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o D:\publish --self-contained --runtime linux-x64
```

and saw in logs a message about invalid .dll.

Then I correct the .dll and tried to publish self-contained and framework-dependent — both started successfully.

So reason may be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are running a docker container in a Silicon M1 chip, you must define the right platform that you're gonna run the app (`linux-arm64`), for example:

```cs
dotnet publish SampleApp.Web.csproj --self-contained --runtime linux-arm64 -o bin -c Release
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting this error on `Linux` machine for `WorkerService`. Fixed by installing `.Net Core` and its `SDKs` properly.

Answer (score 1):

On top of `GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles`, I also had to replace `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>` with `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`.

So it's probably .NET SDK version installation related.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above helped for me, but there is a difference in my case: my project is an aspnet core 3.1 webapi. I followed the instructions of a [tutorial](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip55.html) and landed at this error message. After a while I came to idea to change the base image in my `dockerfile` from `microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0` to `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime` similar to the [hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-dockerfile-1) on the MS Page about docker images for ASP.NET Core and the error disappeared.
So I would say the root cause of this error can be an incompatible base image.

Answer (score 1):

Not related to Docker but I got the error when trying to debug a Azure Core Function that I created via the command line (Azure Func Core tools). The launch.json in VS Code did not auto-generate properly when I tried to create a new debugger configuration. I then used the Azure Function extension to recreate a new Function App project and copied the launch.json that was generated. This file worked for me.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to .NET Functions",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach",
      "processId": "${command:azureFunctions.pickProcess}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going through this official docs from the microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows and trying to containerize the application using it, please replace the "DotNet.Docker.dll" with your own project ".dll" file.

This did the trick for me in my case.

Your dll file should be present in:[Work_Folder]/[Backend_Folder]/bin/Release/net6.0/publish

*Note: Theses files might be hidden so good luck finding it.*

Answer (score 1):

I had the error `A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.dylib' required to execute the application was not found in '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.6'.` on MacOS.

After updating the project to `net7.0` the error was still there. Though I was wondering why dotnet was still using the `/6.0.6` folder.

Running `dotnet --list-runtimes` showed that I had version 6.0.6 installed, so I uninstalled according to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-macos#uninstall-net

Then the error was gone and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody using JetBrains Rider on Linux: the error might also be due to [opening the project through a path with a symlink in it](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009427959-Under-Linux-I-cannot-run-my-project-libhostpolicy-so-is-missing).

You simply have to open the project with a path containing the mountpoint (`/mnt/.../path/to/project`)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by removing the runtime identifiers from my csproj:

```json
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;linux-arm;linux-arm64;linux-x64;osx.10.12-x64;ubuntu.14.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

I was building it using multiple runtime targets and it would appear docker doesn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that when i tried to debug, i had chosen .Net Launch settings profile instead of the Azure Functions host profile