# .net core Failed to run as a self-contained app. on a docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I have this Dockerfile for .net core

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["./WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish --self-contained

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

When I run the docker I get the error:

`A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/app/'.`

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285243/a-fatal-error-was-encountered-the-library-libhostpolicy-so-required), and it is not related to my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285243/a-fatal-error-was-encountered-the-library-libhostpolicy-so-required)

Answer (score 5):

--self-contained require a -r (--runtime)

-r, --runtime     The target runtime to publish for. This is used when creating a self-contained deployment.
                                        The default is to publish a framework-dependent application.

I'd start with changing the publish command in Dockerfile to this:

```
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish --self-contained --runtime linux-64
```

## New Part:

I run the below command

```
$ RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish --self-contained
```

and I got below error:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(127,5): error NETSDK1031: It is not supported to build or publish a self-contained application without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier.  Please either specify a RuntimeIdentifier or set SelfContained to false. [/Users/ziaullahkhan/Code/SelfContainedApp/SelfContainedApp.csproj]
```

I changed the command to this:

```
$ dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained --runtime linux-x64 -o out
```

and it published everything successfully.

I then built the docker image. Started shell on the container

```
$ docker run -it khanziaullah/sca bash
root@eb5dc8083aa3:/app/out# ls -l libhostpolicy.so 
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 327384 Sep 13 15:21 libhostpolicy.so
root@eb5dc8083aa3:/app/out# dotnet SelfContainedApp.dll
Hello World!
```

so I see the libhostpolicy.so file.

Try starting a shell and look for your build and copy location for all the dependencies. COPY command might have gone wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I dont think this is the case, im just trying to run .net core project in docker... I did not see anyone doing `--self-contained` and this rais other errors... )-:

Comment: Restore completed in 16.23 ms for /Users/ziaullahkhan/Code/SelfContainedApp/SelfContainedApp.csproj.
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(127,5): error NETSDK1031: It is not supported to build or publish a self-contained application without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier.  Please either specify a RuntimeIdentifier or set SelfContained to false. [/Users/ziaullahkhan/Code/SelfContainedApp/SelfContainedApp.csproj]

Answer (score -8):

Try to add the following code to the csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="1.0.1" />
```