# The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I am using docker to run the asp.net core 3.1 MVC application.
I am able to build the image but when I run the image it throws the following error:

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the /app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Shopping2.runtimeconfig.json file specifying the appropriate framework.
```

**Dockerfile**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Shopping2.csproj", "Shopping2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Shopping2/Shopping2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Shopping2"
RUN dotnet build "Shopping2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Shopping2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Shopping2.dll"]
```

I am not really sure how to use runtimeconfig.json.
I added the following after reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/)

**Shopping2.runtimeconfig.json**

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "3.1.0"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Concurrent": false,
      "System.Threading.ThreadPool.MinThreads": 4,
      "System.Threading.ThreadPool.MaxThreads": 25
    }
  }
}
```

It made no difference at all.

I tried adding `<GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>`  according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59185091/2064292) but then it started giving me a different error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'Shopping2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Here is a screenshot of the application settings
[image]

And the following is my **.csproj**:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles> // adding this changed the error
    <StartupObject></StartupObject>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>

  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: installing libs on a Linux container is very tricky, you may have to search for the libraries to know how to install them, then retry running your app, if something is wrong (usually another dependency may be missing), repeat the step until it runs OK. There may be some libs installed unnecessarily at the end, but it has no much harm.

Comment: Did you try to change `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>` to `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`, as mentioned in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3935#issuecomment-576236978)?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes,. I tried all three possible values. Library, Exe and Console. But no luck. I finally managed to make it work by moving the Dockerfile outside where solution file is. Earlier it was at the same level as project file as added by visual studio. Now I am able to build and run image but I can no longer use visual studio's run as docker feature. I have to select either the project or IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by a wrong `COPY` on the `Dockerfile`.

For debugging this kind of error you should build the docker image removing (commenting) all lines starting from `RUN dotnet build..` and below, then launch the image as

`docker run -it <imagename> /bin/sh`

On the prompt run `ls` you should see a different folders tree than expected.

On this particular case

```
WORKDIR /src
# cd /src (create if not exist)

COPY ["Shopping2.csproj", "Shopping2/"] 
# Copy the csproj is in /src/Shopping2/Shopping.csproj

RUN dotnet restore "Shopping2/Shopping2.csproj"
# Restore in the /src/Shopping2/ folder

COPY . .
# THE ERROR!
# The content of the Docker run command folder is copied into /src
# probably on the docker image we have 
# /src/obj
# /src/bin
# /src/<all sources>
# /src/Shopping2/shopping2.csproj

WORKDIR "/src/Shopping2"
# cd to /src/Shopping2

RUN dotnet build "Shopping2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
# The error on build
# The compiler found ONLY the .csproj and the restored packages, it don't find the source code
```

The author solves the error by moving the Dockerfile outside the source folder and on the command `COPY . .` docker copy the `Shopping2` to `/src`, it found the same folder and merge all.

Comment: what is it when you get the same error but have never once had docker