# A fatal error encountered 'libhostpolicy.so' required

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerfile, csproj

I am new with docker, running a dotnet core 3.1 project followed the following tutorial(*from the heading Create a container*): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows

and I ran in the following error:
[image]

The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/App/'. Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the /App/CurseOfTheRandomness.runtimeconfig.json file specifying the appropriate framework.

Now I know that a couple of Threads on this problem already exist: [A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285243/a-fatal-error-was-encountered-the-library-libhostpolicy-so-required) .

I tried all of these and multiple combinations of these but I kept getting back on this same error.

.csproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{BDE4CAC4-D370-4E15-8A4C-8748034293D4}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>CurseOfTheRandomness</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>CurseOfTheRandomness</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Discord.Net.Commands, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Discord.Net.Commands.2.4.0\lib\net461\Discord.Net.Commands.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Discord.Net.Core, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Discord.Net.Core.2.4.0\lib\net461\Discord.Net.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Discord.Net.Rest, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Discord.Net.Rest.2.4.0\lib\net461\Discord.Net.Rest.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Discord.Net.Webhook, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Discord.Net.Webhook.2.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Discord.Net.Webhook.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Discord.Net.WebSocket, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Discord.Net.WebSocket.2.4.0\lib\net461\Discord.Net.WebSocket.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Google.Apis, Version=1.51.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Google.Apis.1.51.0\lib\net45\Google.Apis.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.51.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Google.Apis.Auth.1.51.0\lib\net45\Google.Apis.Auth.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices, Version=1.51.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Google.Apis.Auth.1.51.0\lib\net45\Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Google.Apis.Core, Version=1.51.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Google.Apis.Core.1.51.0\lib\net45\Google.Apis.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Google.Apis.PlatformServices, Version=1.51.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Google.Apis.1.51.0\lib\net45\Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Google.Apis.YouTube.v3, Version=1.51.0.2294, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.1.51.0.2294\lib\net45\Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.5.0.1\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Collections.Immutable.1.3.1\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81\System.Collections.Immutable.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Interactive.Async, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Interactive.Async.4.0.0\lib\net461\System.Interactive.Async.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Linq.Async, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Linq.Async.4.0.0\lib\net461\System.Linq.Async.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.3\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Modules\Commands.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

And here is the Dockerfile I invoked in the first image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
COPY ./bin/Debug/ App/
COPY ./Properties App/
WORKDIR ./App
ENV COMPlus_EnableDiagnostics=0
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","CurseOfTheRandomness.exe"]
```

I know there are multiple instances where this error occurs. Still I'd like to know: why, how and when does this error happen?

Comment: Please show text *as text* rather than as screenshots. It's *much* easier to read as text. Also, please try to reproduce this with a *minimal* example - I expect you'd be able to show this with a trivial console app instead of one with huge numbers of dependencies. Additionally, it looks like you're using .NET 4.6.1 references despite building a Linux docker image. I wouldn't expect you to need all those `<Reference>` elements at all...

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to with a *minimal example*, Do you mean I create a new Console App on the same framework and make a docker image and run this on a docker container?

Also *yes* I do need all these References, they are referencing to dependencies I use in my project. I did run dotnet --version and it is 3.1.114 so idk about .NET 4.6.1.

Thanks for the reply I changed my Thread accordingly

Comment: I mean "the smallest possible example that demonstrates the problem." It doesn't help that it looks like you've got an old-style project instead of an SDK-style project which is easier to use and more appropriate for .NET Core. But your project is actually targeting .NET 4.7.2, which isn't the same as .NET Core that you're trying to use in your Dockerfile. If you're actually trying to use .NET Core, I suggest you start a new project with `dotnet new` and work from that... this mixture of .NET Framework and .NET Core is going to be really confusing *and* verbose for no benefit.

Comment: (With .NET Core, I suspect your project file can be about 20 lines long, instead of the large one you've got at the moment... *and* then it would match what you're using in the Dockerfile.)

Comment: You're right, I didn't use the .NET core frameworks... I thought I did until I had a second look. Now I did change the project target to 3.1 and came across a different error but that'll make possibly another thread.