# libhostpolicy.so required to execute app not found in '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.4

Tags: .net, .net-core, fedora

I had .NetCore installed on fedora 37 but whatever I execute I get "the specified command or file was not found. Possible reasons for this include", so I removed naything related to dotnet using

```
sudo dnf remove dotnet*
```

which was succesful, then I issued

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-7.0
```

which was succesful. When I tried

```
dotnet --version
```

I get

> A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required
> to execute the application was not found in
> '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.4'.

Output for dotnet --info

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.4'.

Host:
  Version:      7.0.5
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       8042d61b17

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.202 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.11 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.14 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.15 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/usr/lib64/dotnet]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285243/a-fatal-error-was-encountered-the-library-libhostpolicy-so-required

Comment: Hans, the link you porovided has nothing to do with my thread. Even before creating a project, basic dot commands are failing and I am not using docker

Comment: Good, the answers there have nothing to do with docker either.

Comment: Hans, I suggest you visit this thread to understand the problem and the solution which has nothing with docker. https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/31705       The 1st line in the link you provided, I insist says    "I am running dotnet core 2.0 console project. Ran into the following error when trying to run it from **Docker**"